# How do I set a standard elevated button theme in Flutter 3.16?

Tags: flutter, dart, material3, flutter3.x

It looks like when I upgraded from Flutter 3.10 to 3.16, they are now using something called material 3 to define standard for Flutter elements. This changed the entire look of my app. I don't want to just set `useMaterial3` to `false` because Flutter recommends to use this for new work. How do I quickly override the standard ElevatedButton theme to give it the look I want everywhere in my app? I know I can go to each button and change its style, but given how far I am in the project that would take way too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default theme for ElevatedButtons by setting up a custom theme for your app. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Override the default theme for ElevatedButton
    final ThemeData theme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue), // Set your desired background color
          textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(color: Colors.white)), // Set your desired text color
          // Add more customizations as needed
        ),
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: theme,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Your button action
          },
          child: Text('Custom ElevatedButton'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, `elevatedButtonTheme` within the `ThemeData` allows you to override the default style for all ElevatedButtons in your app. Adjust the properties under `ButtonStyle` to customize the look of the ElevatedButton as you desire.

Comment: That works, thanks! Do you think you could upvote my question so that future readers can easily see this in search results?

Comment: Of cource I think it usefull for others